# "Fraïssé limits" without amalgamation

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, model-theory

*All structures are countable with countable signature.*

Given a structure $\mathcal{A}$, the *age* of $\mathcal{A}$, $Age(\mathcal{A})$, is the set of structures isomorphic to finitely-generated substructures of $\mathcal{A}$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_(model_theory)). (This isn't really a set, but we can restrict attention to those structures contained in $H_{\omega_{17}}$, say.) $Age(\mathcal{A})$ automatically satisfies the Joint Embedding and Hereditariness properties, but may lack the Amalgamation property: an example of this is the undirected graph $\mathcal{G}$ with integers as vertices, and an edge between ever pair $(z, z+1)$.

Given a collection $\mathbb{K}$ of finite structures closed under isomorphism with the Joint Embedding, Hereditariness, and Amalgamation properties, we can form the *Fraïssé limit* of $\mathbb{K}$, the unique homogeneous structure $F(\mathbb{K})$ with $Age(F(\mathbb{K}))=\mathbb{K}$. Specifically, let $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{K})=\mathbb{P}$ be the poset whose elements are finite sequences $\emptyset\prec \mathcal{A}_0\prec . . . \prec\mathcal{A}_n$ of structures in $\mathbb{K}$, ordered by reverse extension; then forcing with $\mathbb{P}$ produces the Fraïssé limit. Formally, there is a countable collection $\mathcal{D}$ of dense sets in $\mathbb{P}$ such that the direct limit of the terms of any $\mathcal{D}$-generic filter through $\mathbb{P}$ is isomorphic to the Fraïssé limit.

Now if $\mathbb{K}$ lacks the Amalgamation property, there will be no homogeneous structure with age $\mathbb{K}$. The poset $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{K})$, however, still makes sense, and we can consider the collection $Fil(\mathbb{K})$ of all structures formed by (taking direct limits of terms of) maximal filters through $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{K})$.

Moreover, we can compare structures in $Fil(\mathbb{K})$ in terms of relative genericity. For $D\subseteq \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{K})$ dense, let $\mathcal{O}_D$ be the set of structures which can be built by filters hitting $D$. These sets $\mathcal{O}_D$ then generate a topology $\tau_\mathbb{K}$ on $Fil(\mathbb{K})$. This space is terrible, but seems reasonably natural if what we're interested in is how generic elements of $Fil(\mathbb{K})$ are.

As it turns out, elements of $Fil(\mathbb{K})$ can be extremely generic, even though the Fraïssé limit as such may not exist. Specifically, let $Gen(\mathbb{K})$ be the class of isomorphism classes of structures $\mathcal{A}$ such that in every open $\mathcal{O}_D$ there is a copy $\mathcal{B}\cong\mathcal{A}$. Then, for example, consider the graph $\mathcal{G}$ from the first paragraph and let $\mathbb{K}=Age(\mathcal{G})$. $Fil(\mathbb{K})$ is precisely the class of acyclic infinite graphs in which each vertex has degree at most 2. However, the graph $\mathcal{G}$ is special among these graphs, since there is a countable collection $\mathcal{D}$ of dense subsets of $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{K})$ such that any $\mathcal{D}$-generic filter corresponds to $\mathcal{G}$. This means $Gen(\mathbb{K})=\{\mathcal{G}\}$, and so in some sense $\mathcal{G}$ is the closest thing to a Fraisse limit of $Age(\mathcal{G})$ as we might reasonably expect to exist.

In general, if $Gen(Age(\mathcal{A}))$ has precisely one element, denote that element by $G(\mathcal{A})$, and call it the *generalized Fraïssé limit* of $Age(\mathbb{A})$.

---

My questions are as follows. First, the obvious:

> What are some sources for learning about this construction? In particular, what's it *actually* called?

Second,

> When is $Gen(Age(\mathcal{A}))$ nonempty? When does it have exactly one element?

Finally, the fact that $G(\mathcal{G})=\mathcal{G}$ motivates me to ask:

> Suppose $Gen(Age(\mathcal{A}))$ has exactly one element. What can we say about $G(\mathcal{A})$ in relation to $\mathcal{A}$? For example, what structures $\mathcal{A}$ do we have $G(\mathcal{A})=\mathcal{A}$?

A couple quick observations: any homogeneous structure $\mathcal{A}$ will certainly have $G(\mathcal{A})=\mathcal{A}$. On the other hand, consider the graph $\mathcal{G}_\omega$ consisting of the disjoint union of infinitely many copies of $\mathcal{G}$; then $G(\mathcal{G}_\omega)=\{\mathcal{G}\}$, so not every structure has this property even if it has singleton $Gen$. Finally, note that we will always have $G(G(\mathcal{A}))=G(\mathcal{A})$ if $G(\mathcal{A})$ exists.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This question has been around for a long time, and the OP himself has known the answer for almost as long! But just in the interest of putting some references out there, I'll give an answer:

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a class of finite structures. Then $Gen(\mathbb{K})$ contains a unique isomorphism class $M_{\mathbb{K}}$ (often called the generic limit of $\mathbb{K}$) if and only if $\mathbb{K}$ is countable up to isomorphism, has the JEP, and has the weak amalgamation property:

(WAP) For any $A\in \mathbb{K}$, there exists $B\in \mathbb{K}$ and an embedding $f\colon A\to B$ such that for all $C_1,C_2\in \mathbb{K}$ and embeddings $g_1\colon B\to C_1$ and $g_2\colon B\to C_2$, there exists $D\in \mathbb{K}$ and embeddings $h_1\colon C_1\to D$ and $h_2\colon C_2\to D$ such that $h_1\circ g_1\circ f = h_2\circ g_2\circ f$:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
A @>f>> B\\
@VfVV @VVg_1V\\
B @. C_1\\
@Vg_2VV @Vh_1VV\\
C_2 @>h_2>> D
\end{CD}
Note that we don't require $h_1\circ g_1 = h_2\circ g_2$, so the images of $B$ in $D$ under $h_1\circ g_1$ and $h_2\circ g_2$ may be different.

The usual amalgamation property (AP) has the same statement, but with $B = A$ and $f = \text{id}_A$.

References: The equivalence between WAP and the existence of a generic limit was identified by Ivanov in his paper [Generic expansions of $\omega$-categorical structures and semantics of generalized quantifiers](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2586500) and independently by Kechris and Rosendal in their paper [Turbulence, amalgamation and generic automorphisms of homogeneous structures](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0409567). A clear presentation (in the wider context of finitely generated structures) can be found in the recent paper [Games on finitely generated structures](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.05756) by Krawczyk and Kubiś. I also gave an exposition (in the wider context of classes of finite structures with specified "strong embeddings" between them) in [my PhD thesis](https://akruckman.faculty.wesleyan.edu/files/2019/07/thesis.pdf) (Section 4.2).

So that answers the first and second questions. For the third question, a structure $M$ is the generic limit of its age if and only if it satisfies weak homogeneity: For any substructure $A\leq M$, there is an embedding $f\colon A\to B$ (with $B\in Age(M)$) such that for any embedding $g\colon B\to C$ (with $C\in Age(M)$), $C$ embeds in $M$ over $A$, i.e. there is an embedding $h\colon C\to M$ such that $h\circ g\circ f$ is the inclusion of $A$ into $M$.

The condition of weak homogeneity is implicitly there in Ivanov's original paper (since it's what powers the back-and-forth argument establishing uniqueness of the generic limit), but he doesn't give it a name. Again, my thesis is a reference for this equivalence.

Comment: Holy crud, I completely forgot about this question - thanks for putting it to rest! (And I think it's worth pointing out that the only reason I knew all this was because you explained it to me!)

Comment: I have replaced the dead link http://pages.iu.edu/~akruckma/thesis.pdf by https://akruckman.faculty.wesleyan.edu/files/2019/07/thesis.pdf - although it seems that there are also [some other links](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=Infinitary+Limits+of+Finite+Structures+Kruckman) which could be used instead.

Answer (score 5):

Kubiś wrote a lot on this subject.

[This.](https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.1683)

[This.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.03300)

I also have a [small](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.02738) contribution on this subject.

There is also an even more abstract [point of view](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2275577), started by Rosický in '80.

> The general motto is that the amalgamation property has a key role in the construction of the Fraïssé limit, any weakening of it corresponds to a weakening of the universal property limit.

Comment: Hi Ivan, your last link is broken, can you fix it?

Comment: @DavidRoberts, done!

Comment: thanks, slowly getting through the list of broken JSL links :-)